# MATLAB: Converting 3D matrix to cell array

Tags: matlab, matrix, cell

My goal is to convert `192x88x3` matrix to `3x1` cell array which includes `192x88` arrays. I used `mat2cell` in MATLAB but the result is `1x1x3` cell array which looks weird.

```
a=rand(192,88,3);
b=mat2cell(a, [192],[88],[1 1 1])
whos b
b         1x1x3            405840  cell
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`squeeze`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/squeeze.html) to remove redundant singleton dimensions.

```
b = squeeze(mat2cell(a, [192],[88],[1 1 1]));
```